# Ensure the existence of a layer before proceeding with code

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a simple plugin I made with multiple `QgsMapLayerComboBox` to select layers on which I'm running some processing algorithms.

In some instances, certain layers don't exist, yet I would still like to run algorithms on the other layers.

The only method I recall finding and using was:

```
if 'part of the layers name' in locals():
    Run a couple processing algorithms
```

which is essentially always ignored.

Is there a way to consistently verify the existence of a layer as a condition to proceed with code? The `QgsMapLayerComboBox` would then just be ignored, regardless of the default layer it takes from the filter I added to it.

Edit:

I have also tried doing it this way:

```
if self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer().name():
    LayerName = self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer().name()
    Layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(LayerName)[0]
```

And then check whether the layer exists prior to attempting processing it this way:

```
if Layer:
   do something
```

But I receive an error at my first if:

```
2022-02-10T08:24:21     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My/plugin/.py/location", line 233, in FunctionName
  if self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer().name():
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Do they exist in the canvas, or as in-memory layer objects?

Comment: @Matt Excuse me if I fail to understand your question properly, they're shapefile layers. I have edited my question with an added attempt which didn't work either

Comment: Your check is in slightly the wrong place. You could do something like `currentLayer = self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()` then `if currentLayer:  # do something`. If the layer exists then you already have it by using `self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()`. You don't need to find it again using `.mapLayersByName()`.

Comment: You're right, I was getting NoneType error because I was checking for a variable that would otherwise not be assigned in the first place. It does work now. Thank you.